# Performing arithmetic operations on isolated arraylist elements

Tags: java, algorithm, math, arraylist, addition

I am looking for a clear **explanation** to my question (NOT looking for code), but if a bit of code helps to explain yourself, then please do.. thank you :)

Question:

-using Java
-Main class asks user for 2 integer inputs, then places them into 2 arraylists, of type integer. Each digit is broken up and stored in its own index, so it is its own "element", so to speak.

For example, with my code right now, it goes something like this:

"Please enter an integer:"

688

"Please enter another integer:"

349

---

At this point now, internally, I have stored the input as 2 arraylists, that look like this:

ArrayList1: [6, 8, 8]

ArrayList2: [3, 4, 9]

Now, lets say I want to perform some addition, such as ArrayList1 + ArrayList2.

I'll probably go ahead and create a temporary 'result' arraylist, then move that answer over to arraylist1 when my calculation is complete.

But the part I am having trouble with, is coming up with a systematic clear way to add the arraylists together. Keep in mind that this example uses an arraylist which represents an integer of length 3, but this could be anything. I could, for example, have an arraylist with 50 elements, such as [2, 4, 4, 3, 7, 3, 6, 3,.............] which could represent a huge number in the trillions, etc.

Comment: Do you want the result in one already existing array (like += would behave for int)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about how you would do grade-school addition.  You'd start up by lining up the numbers like this:

```
    1  3  7
+      4  5
-----------
```

Then, you'd add the last two digits to get

```
    1  3  7
+      4  5
-----------
          2
```

And you'd have a carry of 1.  You then add the next two digits, plus the carry:

```
    1  3  7
+      4  5
-----------
       8  2
```

Now you have carry 0, so you can add the last digit and the missing digit to get

```
    1  3  7
+      4  5
-----------
    1  8  2
```

The general pattern looks like this: starting from the last digit of each array, add the last two numbers together to get a sum and a carry.  Write the units digit of the sum into the resulting array, then propagate the carry to the next column.  Then add the values in that column (plus the carry) together, and repeat this process across the digits.  Once you have exhausted all of the digits in one of the numbers, continue doing the sum, but pretend that there's a 0 as the missing digit.  Once you have processed all the digits, you will have the answer you're looking for.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you store digits backwards, your arrays will be much easier to manipulate, because their ones, tens, hundreds, etc. will be aligned with each other (i.e. they will be sitting at the same index).

You could then implement the addition the same way they teach in the elementary school: go through arrays of digits one by one, add them, check for digit overflow (`>=10`), and pay attention to the carry flag (result digit is `(a+b) % 10`, carry flag is `(a+b)/10`). If the carry flag is not zero when you are done with the addition, and there are no additional digits remaining on either side, add the carry flag to the end of the result array.

The only remaining issue is displaying the lists. You can do it with a simple backward loop.

P.S. If you would like to double-check your mulch-trilion calculation against something that is known to work, use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to compute the expected results, and check your results against theirs.

Comment: @JohnSmith `reverse` actually reverses the list - it is a lot more expensive than simply iterating the list backwards. This is important if you are looking to print intermediate results while keeping your data intact for continuing your calculations.

Comment: @JohnSmith You can do multiplication in a similar way to how you do it on paper. First, implement multiplication of an array by a digit - it is a matter of propagating a carry flag, which can be as high as eight, through the length of the new array. Then you implement a shift by one digit, which is as simple as adding an extra zero to the end of the list. Finally, use the addition routine that you have written already.

Answer (score 0):

Think of an arraylist as a storage container. It can hold items in it that are of type "integer", but it's type is still "storage container". You can't perform math on these type of objects--only their contents.

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
list1
list2
```

and need an extra variable

```
int carry
```

then

```
1 do add(0,0) on short list, so that at the end two lists have same length.

2 reversely loop the two list. 
  sum=(carry+(e1+e2))
  set e1 (list1 element) = sum%10, 
  carry = sum/10, 
  till the first element.
3 if carry==1, list1.add(0,1)

now list1 stores the result.
```

**Note**, step1 is not a must. it could be done in loop by checking the short list's length.